# Algorithm for sorting Java objects into buckets, then sorting within buckets

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, predicate

I have the need to take an `ArrayList<Conference> conferences`, where `Conference` contains a `public Date beginDate` parameter, and sort as follows: first, separate conferences into buckets which represent unique months for `beginDate`, and then sort on `beginDate` itself within the buckets. I'm sure this is a common need so I was hoping someone here would have some tips.

My idea for this follows. Please tell me why it is sub-optimal :)

1. Create a `HashMap<Date, ArrayList<Conference>>`.
2. Iterate over `conferences` and use a special static function to find the first day of the month of their `beginDate`, check if there is an `ArrayList<Conference>` for that `Date`. then add them to the `ArrayList` for that `Date` (which should all be the same because `first_day_of_month(any_day_in_month)` is the same.
3. Iterate over each `ArrayList` member of the `HashMap` and use a standard sorting procedure to sort the `ArrayList` by date.

This seems more complicated than necessary, but please let me know why it's bad and what can be done to fix it.

Edit: Also, if it matters, I will eventually need to add all of those `ArrayList` back into an `ArrayAdapter` which will go in commonsware's `MergeAdapter`... :(

Comment: I must say that I ended up doing the exact same thing in a completely unrelated field. `HashMap<BigDecimal, ArrayList<ArrayList<dataType>>>`.  It is working very well, even with the need to iterate through the `BigDecimal` keys every time a new entry is added, to make certain I don't duplicate a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sort by the date from the very beginning the month's entries will be subsequent either way. After the initial sorting you can iterate over all entries and make artificial "split" if an entry is the first one of new month. I am not even sure you will need to do such differentiation (maybe becasue the question is a bit vague on this).

The total complexity of the proposed algorithm is `O(nlog n)`, where `n` is the number of elements, and of course there is no better solution.

**NOTE** Btw this algorithm is better than the one proposed by you in operations complexity.

Comment: I think I do need the differentiation because I need to use different Adapters to add to a `MergeAdapter`, which can handle a sequential array of views and adapters... So you are saying do the sort up front, then when I find the first new month, add it to a new arraylist?

Comment: @jshin47 Yup, that's it basically. Just replace `the first new month` with `for every new month found` to be more precise.